# Cannot connect to Kafka Docker-container from other container: Connection refused - 1/1 brokers are down

Tags: .net, docker, apache-kafka

I am trying to hook up a data-aggregator to a kafka-broker The intent is to collect data from a HTTP Endpoint, and save that to a database periodically. Both are run in docker, using the following docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"

services:
  zk:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.0.0
    container_name: zk
    ports:
      - 2181:2181
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
    restart: on-failure:5
  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.0.0
    container_name: kafka
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
      - 9094:9094
    environment:
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zk:2181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INSIDE://kafka:9092,OUTSIDE://localhost:9094
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: INSIDE://0.0.0.0:9092,OUTSIDE://0.0.0.0:9094
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INSIDE:PLAINTEXT,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INSIDE
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: "true"
      KAFKA_NUM_PARTITIONS: 4
    restart: on-failure:5
  tinygator-metric-aggregator:
    image: tinygator.aggregator:latest
    container_name: tg-aggregator
    environment:
      KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVER: localhost:9094
      KAFKA_TOPIC: test
      METRIC_ENDPOINT: "http://localhost:15672/api/queues/%2F/Test?sort=message_stats.publish_details.rate&sort_reverse=true&columns=name,message_stats.publish_details.rate,message_stats.deliver_get_details.rate"
      METRIC_METHOD: GET
      METRIC_INTERVAL: 5000
      METRIC_HEADERS: '{"authorization":"Basic Z3Vlc3Q6Z3Vlc3Q="}'
    restart: on-failure:5
```

Kafka and zk seem to start normally. However, I get the following error for the aggregator:

```
tg-aggregator                  | %3|1576348274.043|FAIL|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:0.0.0.0:9094/bootstrap]: 0.0.0.0:9094/bootstrap: Connect to ipv4#0.0.0.0:9094 failed: Connection refused (after 4704ms in state CONNECT)
tg-aggregator                  | %3|1576348274.048|ERROR|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:0.0.0.0:9094/bootstrap]: 0.0.0.0:9094/bootstrap: Connect to ipv4#0.0.0.0:9094 failed: Connection refused (after 4704ms in state CONNECT)
tg-aggregator                  | %3|1576348274.048|ERROR|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:0.0.0.0:9094/bootstrap]: 1/1 brokers are down
tg-aggregator                  | Unhandled exception. System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Cannot assign requested address
tg-aggregator                  |  ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (99): Cannot assign requested address
tg-aggregator                  |    at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
tg-aggregator                  |    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
tg-aggregator                  |    at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
tg-aggregator                  |    at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean allowHttp2, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
tg-aggregator                  |    at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
tg-aggregator                  |    at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttpConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
tg-aggregator                  |    at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
tg-aggregator                  |    at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
tg-aggregator                  |    at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
tg-aggregator                  |    at MetricAggregator.Program.Main(String[] args) in /app/Program.cs:line 83
tg-aggregator                  |    at MetricAggregator.Program.<Main>(String[] args)
```

Now, me and a colleague have been sitting on this for hours now (we are both super new to Kafka). The issue does not occur for the guy who has written the aggregator (can be found under https://github.com/Azer0s/TinyGator) on MacOS. I am on Windows 10, my colleague is on Arch. We have tried a lot of different port numbers, ways to set the Kafka listeners and advertised listeners, etc. In short, we are at a complete loss.

Does anyone have an idea?

UPDATE:

After reading up on Kafka listeners, I have now modified my docker-compose, changing the address on which the aggregator is trying to connect:

```
KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVER: kafka:9092
```

But error is still the same.

Comment: `kafka:9092` is correct... I don't think your new error is Kafka related. For example, `METRIC_ENDPOINT` shouldn't use localhost, should it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error is coming from the [metrics endpoint](https://github.com/Azer0s/TinyGator/blob/master/src/MetricAggregator/Program.cs#L72-L83), which is called **before** the Kafka message is being sent.

That suggests your metrics endpoint URL is incorrect, as `localhost` would be the container itself (which is pulling metrics, not having metrics itself or exposing an HTTP interface)

The example looks like it's pulling [RabbitMQ queue statistics](https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html#http-api)

---

In any case, `kafka:9092` is correct in your context

> The issue does not occur for the guy who has written the aggregator

I'm sure it would, if he had given an invalid metrics endpoint

Comment: We have also realized this. It seems something went wrong with the Request headers (RabbitMQ API has basic auth). Nevertheless, this was the correct answer. Thank you!